# Magento checkout page goes blank when checking out also product image not uploading

Tags: magento2, magento-1.8, php

hello everyone am new in magento and am trying to built a site in magento everything working prefect on localhost but not working on server when i checkout also product image not uploading .checkout page is showing blank
am getting this error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 786432 bytes) in /home/rails/public_html/shoperhub/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 2440

```
Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 786432 bytes)
    [file] => /home/rails/public_html/shoperhub/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php
    [line] => 2440
)
```

I have already changed  in .htaccess file.

```
 php_value memory_limit 256M
 php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you only have 32MB of allocated memory on your server.
Magento requires a minimum of 256 and a recommended 512.
Even if you set in `.htaccess` this `php_value memory_limit 256M` it seams that your setting is not taken  into consideration.
Maybe you are not allowed to override that value from `.htaccess`.
Check this with your hosting provider.